# How to visualise the relationship between two nodes in Neo4j using d3.js?

Tags: ruby, d3.js, neo4j, neo4j.rb, visualize

I've wrote a cypher query to show the relationship between two movie nodes:

```
MATCH (m1:Movie)-[r*1..2]-(m2:Movie)
where m1.movieID = '1' AND m2.movieID = '2'
RETURN r
LIMIT 25
```

It's returns this in the Neo4j browser, and this is exactly what I want to create in d3.js. Eventually the movieIDs will be parameters, so the results will be different for each pair of movies.

[image]

I've been following the Neo4j-core Ruby example [seen here](https://github.com/neo4j-examples/movies-ruby-neo4j-core/blob/master/movies.rb) to create my own graph, but my problem is that I can't `RETURN` common nodes between the two moves, i.e `Tag`/`Country` nodes.

How should I solve this problem? Should I create a query to return the two movies, and another query to return the common nodes between them? How would I write this latter query? I'm really stuck on how I can visualise this relationship...

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you should try matching the path rather than the relationships as you are right now.  Something like:

```
MATCH p=(m1:Movie { movieID: 1 } )-[r*1..2]-(m2:Movie { movieID: 2 } )
RETURN p;
```

You can then use [collection functions](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-functions-collection.html) on the path object `p` to do whatever you like with it.  For example, if you want to get the inner nodes, you can use `nodes(p)` and simply remove the first and last nodes (which would be `m1` and `m2`) and get the nodes along the path.

Answer (score 0):

You could return the movies with the relationships:

```
MATCH (m1:Movie)-[r*1..2]-(m2:Movie)
WHERE m1.movieID = '1' AND m2.movieID = '2'
RETURN m1, m2, r
LIMIT 25
```

Though that might give you duplication.  If you're going to be displaying this with D3 probably what you want is all of the relationships involved and their start/end nodes.  To do that you could do:

```
MATCH (m1:Movie)-[rels*1..2]-(m2:Movie)
WHERE m1.movieID = '1' AND m2.movieID = '2'
RETURN rels
UNWIND rels AS r
WITH DISTINCT r AS rel
WITH startnode(rel) AS startnode, endnode(rel) AS endnode, rel
LIMIT 25
```

Generally what you want to end up with is a collection of nodes and relationships involved.  So with the result of that query you might do:

```
result = neo4j_session.query(query_string)

data = {nodes: [], relationships: []}
result.each do |row|
  data[:nodes] << row.startnode
  data[:nodes] << row.endnode
  data[:relationships] << row.rel
end

data[:nodes].uniq!
```

Comment: For `data[:relationships]` wouldn't you also need the source and the target node? Won't `row.rel` return only the relationship property (if one exists)?

Comment: `rel` returns the relationship object (if you're in server mode that will be a `CypherRelationship` object) which should have `start_node_neo_id` and `end_node_neo_id` methods